# "Ionic start projectName" not working with Ionic Framework

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04`.

I've followed a couple of tutorials on how to install the Ionic Framework on Ubuntu 14.04, including the [official guide](http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/), basically just doing the following:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Then I run the command `ionic start myproject`, but I just get no response...just a new line in the terminal, and when I check the directory, nothing has been created. I also tried `sudo ionic start myproject`, but that also just returns a new line and the project has not been created.

I have also run `ionic --help`, which again returns a new line and nothing else.

when I run `npm ls`, I can see that both cordova and ionic have been installed globally.

What do I need to do in order to get ionic up and running, so that I can run the command `ionic start whateverProject` and have a new project created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/538996/executing-certain-commands-do-absolutely-nothing

In short: let `$(which node)` point to `$(which nodejs)`, for example using a symlink

Comment: I dont know why this is downvoted. I had exactly the same problem on the same os, and this solution helps, even its somewhat weird.

Comment: Complementing this anwser you could install nodejs-legacy that does that for you

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to follow this steps:-

1. ionic start myApp tabs
2. cd myApp
3. ionic platform add android
4. ionic build android
5. ripple emulate --path www
6. ionic emulate android