# Installing Ionic framework- setting up env variables - Not working.

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to JS and I am planning to build a simple application

I was installing ionic and cordova using `npm -g install ionic`, did the same for cordova also.

it gets installed in `/usr/local/lib/ionic` this ionic points to -> `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic`

I basically get this

```
/usr/local/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
ionic@1.2.8 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic
├── connect-livereload@0.4.0
├── progress@1.1.7
├── open@0.0.5
├── colors@0.6.2
├── ncp@0.4.2
```

Now how do I set my env variables?

```
export IONIC="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic"
export PATH=$PATH:$IONIC/bin
```

Is this right?

I also tried downloading the ionic files, put them under `/home/softwares/ionic` and changed the bashrc to

```
export IONIC="~/softwares/ionic"
export PATH=$PATH:IONIC
```

what about this? 
TO put it short, npm install of ionic does not work. so if i `ionic -v` or try `ionic start blahblah blank` nothing comes up.

Comment: When you install with NPM it should set the appropriate variables for you, allowing you to run ionic -v from the command line.  I think you're using Linux, so look at the lines of the following script: http://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/ You'll see nothing special needs to be set in the realm of Ionic or Cordova.  Only the Android SDK.

Comment: I ran his script too. It still did not work. I ran his script, then installed build-tools(19 and 20) , 19+ has got ionic. Still nothing. That is why I am sort off stuck!

Comment: What OS specifically and what architecture?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64bit.

Comment: If you do:

`file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic`

you should see

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic: Node.js script, ASCII text executable`

Answer (score 0):

Change your node link:

```
#Run

which node
#and in my case it displayed /usr/sbin/node.

#If it says command not found, skip to 3. Remove it by

sudo rm /usr/sbin/node
#Run

which nodejs
#in my case it displayed /usr/bin/nodejs.

#Make a link

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node 
#OR

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node
```

ref: ["Ionic start projectName" not working with Ionic Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155486/ionic-start-projectname-not-working-with-ionic-framework/27195120#27195120)