# Default Install Location: IONIC, NODEJS

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I came accross an issue today, when i installed ionic and cordova for a test project. i did this

`npm install -g cordova ionic`
then 
`ionic start myapp tabs`

Problem that i faced was that nothing happened, i searched around but could not find a reasonable answer. this is what i found:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155486/ionic-start-projectname-not-working-with-ionic-framework
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-start-myapp-tabs-not-working/3205
```

But i believed it is an environment issue. So i cleanedup. removed old builds and did a fresh build but nothing much of success.

Questions:

1) Where is default location for creating the app folder is defined when we do 'start ionic app-name'

2) If app-name folder is not created and command completes without any errors, what should be next course of action.

i hope some one can help out.

`ENV: WINDOWS7, NODE.JS, IONIC, CORDOVA`

Comment: The app folder will be created from where you launch the `ionic start` command and will have `app-name` as name

Comment: @e666 Yes, that is exactly what is not happening, can you suggest alternate course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem (stated above) by upgrading node.js and reinstalling ionic package after removing it.

Second i also found out that to specify path to app location, below command will work.

`ionic start [absolute-path-to-app-folder] [template-optional]`

e.g.

`ionic start c:\myApp` will create a blank app in C drive

Hope this can help someone. i spent a week digging this out.